# WARN grunt-cssc@0.2.6 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.1 but none was installed

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

What is needed here?
I tried to install all the references:

```
>npm install
```

> hertz@1.0.0 C:...\BowerAndGrunt `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@1.0.1
>
> npm WARN grunt-cssc@0.2.6 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.1 but none was
>   installed. npm WARN hertz@1.0.0 No repository field. npm ERR! code 1

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hertz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "legends",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-htmlhint": "0.9.13",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1",
    "matchdep": "1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

```
npm install --save-dev grunt
```

this is because grunt-cssc needs grunt installed but you didnt' define it in your pacakge json.
read more on peer dependencies

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

EDIT:

because it is asking for a grunt which is less than version 1 like you have. checkout semver in npm in following link:

github.com/npm/node-semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1

basically this means that your cssc lib needs grunt 0.4 and not grunt 1 but hopefully it should work with grunt 1 as well.

you can contact lib author and ask him to upgrade to support grunt 1 as well.

Comment: because it is asking for a grunt which is less than version 1 like you have. checkout semver in npm in following link: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1 basically this means that your cssc lib needs grunt 0.4 and not grunt 1 but hopefully it should work with grunt 1 as well. you can contact lib author and ask him to upgrade to support grunt 1 as well.

Comment: Your comment is the right answer, just include i in your post. Thanks